# POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when integrating shippo with Exception has occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, shippo

I'm working on a project where I'm using shippo to get my shipping labels. Recently, my computer restarted, and I had an issue where `mongodb` wasn't connecting. I finally, got `mongodb` to reconnect by reinstalling and then reconnecting it, but when it did none of my data was there, so I ended up recreating most of it. I've been trying to create new test orders since my old ones are no longer available, but I can't because now my shippo integration is not working, and I am getting `POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/shippo/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in my console. I don't understand why this is happening, since everything was working properly before the restart. I tried to run a debugger and it's giving me an error stating: `Exception has occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

This is what I have:

```
import express from 'express';
import shippo from 'shippo';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from './models/userModel.js';
const shippoToken = "";
const shippoClient = shippo(shippoToken);

const shippoRouter = express.Router();

shippoRouter.post(
    '/', 
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

var addressFrom  = {
    "name": "req.body.name1",
    "street1": "req.body.street11",
    "city": "req.body.city1",
    "state": "req.body.state1",
    "zip": "req.body.zip1",
    "country": "req.body.country1"
};

var addressTo = {/*shippoClient.address.create({*/
    "name": req.body.name,
    "street1": req.body.street1,
    "street2": req.body.street2,
    "city": req.body.city,
    "state": req.body.state,
    "zip": req.body.zip,
    "country": req.body.country,
    "phone": req.body.phone,
    "email":req.body.email,
    "validate": true,
};
//function(err, address) {
    // asynchronously called
//});
    // asynchronously called

/*console.log(req.body);
console.log(addressFrom)
console.log(addressTo)*/

var parcel = {
    "length": "5",
    "width": "3",
    "height": "2",
    "distance_unit": "in",
    "weight": ".7",
    "mass_unit": "lb"
};
shippoClient.shipment.create({
    "address_from": addressFrom,
    "address_to": addressTo,
    "parcels": [parcel],
    "async": false
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Deal with an error
    console.log("There was an error creating shipment: %s", err);

}).then(async function(shipment) {
    console.log(shipment)
    const shippingId = shipment.object_id
})
```

I'm getting both of the addresses and the parcel information, but `console.log(shipment)` within

```
.then(async function(shipment) {
    console.log(shipment)
    const shippingId = shipment.object_id
})
```

is giving me `undefined`. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced addresses with actual addresses and cleaned up express related code and converted to nodejs code here:

https://gist.github.com/vyshakhbabji/a4d2414bd9089c51739e7ea17220a1ed

This did work and could retrieve "ShipmentId" . Please verify.